# Is there a class that we can use to host both window form and controls?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build an application that has a container as the workspace. In this workspace, I can drag and drop windows form and controls. I have get the panel drag and drop working, but I can host window in it.

Please let me know if there is such a container class ready for use.

I am using visual studio 2008 and c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an MdiForm for this.  You can either right-click on your project and click `Add | New Item ... | Mdi Parent` or take an existing form in your project and set its `IsMdiContainer` property to `true`.  To have another form "hosted" by the Mdi form, set the child form's `MdiParent` property to your Mdi form and then call the child form's `Show()` method.  The Mdi form can also contain controls just like any other form.